# Angular 2 - routerLink doesn't work with external links

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routerlink

I'm trying to work with routerLink with external links. The links are exposed on index.html (that's like a menu from an external App), like this:

Index.html

```
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a onclick="window.changePage('home')" routerLink="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a onclick="window.changePage('info')" routerLink="/">Info</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

And the problem seems like angular doesn't load RouterModule when I access from this external links. If I navigate by this.router.navigate(....) this works fine.
I put an example here:
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wMvqBeLWFYgmB5M6IXeD?p=preview)

Step 1: Click on Home and in Go to Info button. You can see that "Go to Info" has a routerLink and you can click on it.
Step 2: Refresh the page. Click on Info and you'll see that "Go to Info" can't be clicked it.
How can I force angular load RouterModule with external links?

Comment: It's not supposed to.  Just use a normal link instead of a `routerLink`. `routerLink` also won't work outside Angular components if you are using Angular 2/3/4. If you are using AngularJS 1.x, please change the `angular` tag to `angularjs`.

Comment: I'm working with OP on this problem, I hope I can clarify. Our application's menu exists outside of our Angular 2/4 app as it may have to support some functional areas written with other frameworks (we agree this is a terrible approach, our bosses insist on it). We've got around this by exposing a method using `window['navigateApp'] = () => this.router.navigate`... and calling `window.navigateApp` onclick of menu links. The correct component is rendered, but routerLinks within the rendered component are left without any attributes and do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to router that in your .ts file.

In the anchor tag ,just call the function **window.changePage('home')** and similarly **window.changePage('info')**,and

In .ts file inside the function navigate it.

Answer (score -1):

#### Update

Check the comments and other answer, the following is just a work around

---

@Günter Zöchbauer has already mentioned the solution in the comments

Change your info component as below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  /* use href instead of routerlink*/
  template: `Info HTML
            <a href="/home">Go to Home</a>
  `,
})
export class InfoComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree this would work, but it would cause a complete reload of the entire app code on every menu click, which would negate the benefit of using an SPA framework like Angular

Comment: Like @elf337 said, that will force a reload on the page and that's not what you should do on an Angular app.